# How can I hide the edit button to all users except one (based on user id) on OpenERP 7.0?

Tags: security, permissions, openerp-7

I am developing a module on OpenERP (7.0), and I am pretty stuck: I would like to show the edit button to ONE specific user (in this case, not to whole group, and that user might belong to any random group).

As an example, imagine that I have some request and that, in order to go through the process of that request, I need to ask the opinion of one user on some subject (an expert / consultant on that subject). I have the ID of the "consultant user" that will be emitting his opinion stored in my model.

I might even have to ask a different opinion on a diferent subject to another expert to fullfill that same request. How can I assure that only the users assigned to these "opinion requests" will be able to add their opinion on the view form and all the other viewers will have read only access?

Thanks in advance!

-FC

Comment: Did you find the solution?  I am also looking for the same.  I need to hide 'Edit' option of 'Supplier' (Partner) for a particular user group.  Still trying to find a solution...

Comment: No I didn't. You can hide it (but it will stay always hidden and for everybody) like this <form string="NAMEOFFORM" create="false" edit="false" version="7.0">. I've partially solved this issue using domain rules, in some cases and setting the field attributes to readonly in others. But the edit button is still there...

Comment: Yes I already gone through that `create="false" edit="false"`.  But I am looking for based on user permissions.  I tried many ways, but failed...